# KeyError u'occurred at index 188' in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following piece of code which calculates the number of page views for each user and adds that to a new variable in the DataFrame:

```
def get_user_pageview(row, pageview_spiker_indexed):
    user_id = row['user_id']
    num_pageview = len(pageview_spiker_indexed.ix[user_id])
    #print num_pageview
    return num_pageview

userDF['num_pageview'] = userDF.apply(get_user_pageview, args = (pageview_spiker_indexed,), axis = 1)
```

`

The issue is that I get the following error:

KeyError: ('a342bf9', u'occurred at index 188')

I have done a bit of debugging using print statements inside the function and what is probably going wrong is that the function works fine till it reaches index 188. I cannot seem to fix the problem. Any clues on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post complete Traceback?

Comment: @BarunSharma: The traceback is too long for the comment here. There is another difference that I am observing today. Instead of index 188, I am now getting an error at index 793

Comment: Sorry then!! really difficult to figure out in that case. We dont have the complete code that we can run and identify the error nor do you want to post the Traceback. So we can't even try.